# Why is my code to compare the runtime of two different sorting algorithms displaying the same numbers multiple times?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I am trying to compare the running time between bubble sort and insert sort. It does this on 10 different lists with the first list containing 1000 numbers and then increases by 1000 each time.

The following loop creates the lists and times each list using both methods. It is SUPPOSED to assign each time to a list, and then to another list because the goal is to have a list of lists that I can later use as data points for a graph. Assume `sort_1` and `sort_2` are implemented sorting algorithms

```
counter = 0
empty_list = []
list_limit = 1000
data_point = []
list_of_data_points = []

while list_limit <= 10000:

    while counter < list_limit:
        num = random.randint(1, 10000)
        empty_list.append(num)
        counter += 1
    
    copied_list = list(empty_list)
    bubble_time = sort_1(copied_list)
    insert_time = sort_2(copied_list)

    data_point.clear()
    data_point.append(bubble_time)
    data_point.append(insert_time)
    list_of_data_points.append(data_point)
    print(list_of_data_points)
    list_limit += 1000
```

Now the reason `print(list_of_data_points)` is in the loop is because this is where the error is happening. Everything else is working perfectly, but this is what I get when I run the loop:

```
[[0.10695279999999996, 0.00023099999999998122]]
[[0.43489919999999993, 0.0004752999999999563], [0.43489919999999993, 0.0004752999999999563]]
[[0.9825091000000001, 0.0007314000000000487], [0.9825091000000001, 0.0007314000000000487], [0.9825091000000001, 0.0007314000000000487]]
```

As you can see, it will calculate the times just fine. However, each time it is supposed to add the `data_point` into the list, it seems to be clearing the current list and making each data point the same value.

I am confused because I thought the `append()` method was supposed to just add the current data point list into the larger list of lists (i.e. `list_of_data_points`. Is there something wrong with my while loop or is this a list issue that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: I recommend to check the correctness of your list building by adding lots of print calls to your code.  Best to reduce the counters, like, use 4 instead of 1000 and 20 instead of 10000 - then you can also print your intermediate lists and other intermediate results to see if everything is really "working perfectly".  When you have done that, then you may also be able to explain more clearly what you wanted to achieve and where it failed.

Comment: I did. Everything until I try to append the list works, including the clearing the previous data point list and printing the new current data point list.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
data_point.clear()
```

by

```
data_point = []
```

---

When you do:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

the assignment to b copies the reference to the list, not the actual list.

So, if you latter change a, such as `a[0] = 100`, b will become [100,2,3], as well.

When doing `data_point = []`, you a creating a new list with the new values.

So, in the first time, list_of_data_points will be:
[first_list_under_the_name_of_data_point]

The second time:
[first_list_under_the_name_of_data_point, second_list_under_the_name_of_data_point]

And so on.

On the other hand, when you do `data_point.clear()`, you do not create a new list, so, in the first time:

[first_list_under_the_name_of_data_point]

The second time:

[first_list_under_the_name_of_data_point_but_with_updated_values,
first_list_under_the_name_of_data_point_but_with_updated_values]

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Also thank you for the explanation, I just assumed clearing the list each time was the same as 'creating a new list' but your explanation makes so much sense.

Answer (score 0):

data_point gets cleared, then you append the bubble_time and the insert_time, bubble_time is the same as insert_time but the sort method is a different one.

that means you append the same data 2 time (i guess you just sort it in a different way), but hey if that's what you want, you can do this:

```
data_point = [bubble_time, insert_time] #replace datapoint.clear() with this and don't use the append method
```

i am not that good with english but i am glad if that helped, if i got something wrong feel free to write a comment so i can help as much as i can

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
    
data_point = []
    
for i in range(10):
    num_size = (i+1) * 1000
    random_numbers = list(np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 1000, size=num_size))
    bubble_time = len(random_numbers)
    insert_time = len(random_numbers)
    data_point.insert(i, [bubble_time, insert_time])
```

Maybe, it would be even better for you to work with a dictionary in this case:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
    
data_dict = {}
    
for i in range(10):
    num_size = (i+1) * 1000
    random_numbers = list(np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 1000, size=num_size))
    bubble_time = sum(random_numbers)
    insert_time = len(random_numbers)
    data_dict[num_size]= [bubble_time, insert_time]
print(data_dict)

# Output of print(data_dict)
{'1000': [527103, 1000], '2000': [994513, 2000], '3000': [1490553, 3000], '4000': [2007809, 4000], '5000': [2539145, 5000], '6000': [3039272, 6000], '7000': [3501393, 7000], '8000': [4011519, 8000], '9000': [4526147, 9000], '10000': [5053926, 10000]}
```

I chose len() and sum() in order to have two substitutes for your functions.

Working with this dict enables you to plot the data_points with the correct labels easily, for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lists = sorted(data_dict.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples
x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples
plt.plot(x, [i[0] for i in y])
plt.plot(x, [i[1] for i in y])
plt.show()
```

This might seem a little bit overwhelming; I just wanted to give you a piece of concise, working code. If you are interested into certain aspects/lines/methods that don't make sense to you just ask me!